# jQuery click handler passing event object, getting checkbox status

Tags: jquery

(Sort of a newbie question from someone that is more accustomed to how Flash/ActionScript works.)

Given a checkbox and jQuery click(), how do I do the following:

```
$('#myCheckBox').click (function(event) {
  checkboxState = event.target.attr("checked");
  // now do something with checkboxState
}
```

I.e., I want to get the checkbox checked attribute within the anonymous function because that's the pattern that seems to make the most sense, however I don't know how this can be done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.attr()` needs to be called on a jQuery object:

```
checkboxState = $(event.target).is(':checked');
```

or you could use `this`:

```
checkboxState = $(this).is(':checked');
```

`is(':checked')` returns true/false depending on the state of the checkbox

http://api.jquery.com/is/

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: +1: I definitely vote in favor of `$(this).is(":checked")`. The other way looks funny, and therefore I don't like it ;)

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
$('#myCheckBox').click (function(e) {
     checkboxState  = $(this).is(':checked');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 checkboxState = $(this).is(":checked");
```

Answer (score 1):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burhans/EfwM6/) is not an exact answer, but it is a solution to the question.

Note that I am calling the powBlam() function with `this` within the anonymous function.  In that context, the `this` is the checkbox that was checked.